# How to remove table in MS Word while retaining the text inside of it

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word

Is it possible to remove table in MS Word, while retaining the text inside of it? I'm using Word 2010.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

For Word 2010:

- Select the table
- Go to the Tables Tools / Layout tab on the ribbon
- Press **Convert to Text**

Similar functionality exists in previous versions of Word too.

Comment: Works for Word 2013 as well.

Comment: Same steps still work for Word 2019.  While the table formatting is removed, the formatting of the text itself (bold, italicized, hyperlink, etc.) is maintained.  Thanks!

Comment: That works for tables (and their columns), but not "columns". i.e. page layout -> columns

Answer (score 2):

You could simply cut and paste it into another instance of Word, pasting with "keep text only".
Then afterwards you can just cut n' paste back into the original document. Worked for me.

Comment: This is worse than the accepted & oldest answer, since any formatting, and things like hyperlinks, are removed by Keep Text Only.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out one better. Instead of converting to txt, which doesnt honor the aligment (I had mine centered), simply go to Table Tools, Design. They have a few drop boxes named Border Styles, Line Style, ect. Go to the box with perpendicular perforated lines titled Boarders and select the No Boarder option!

Comment: This really doesn't "remove" the table, but hides the border and keeps the table. It is not really an answer to the original question asked